# How to simulate a conditional expectation given a filtration

Tags: programming, risk-neutral-measure, sde, expected-value, wienerprocess

I had a question regarding how to simulate a certain conditional expectation. I am given two processes $X_1(t), X_2(t)$ which both follow their own SDE, but both are of the form
\begin{equation*}
dX_i(t) = \mu_i X_i (t) dt + \sigma_i X_i(t) dW^{\mathbb{P}}(t), \qquad X_i(t_0)=X_{i, 0}
\end{equation*}
with known constants and the same Wiener process $W^{\mathbb{P}}(t)$. Then I am also given a known risk-free interest rate $r$ and a known range of strike price $K=[0, ..., 10]$ and maturity time $T$.

Given that $M(T)=e^{r T}$, I am asked to use Euler discretisation to find
\begin{equation*}
V(t) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[\frac{f(X(T), Y(T), K)}{M(T)}|\mathcal{F}(t)\right]
\end{equation*}
for every value of $K$ in the range. Here $f$ is just some continuous function, which is also known but not really relevant for my question.

I think I know how to start: I first just replace $\mu_i$ by $r$ since we are dealing with $\mathbb{Q}$. I also already implemented something to calculate $X(t), Y(t)$ for any $t$ given a Wiener process $W(t)$ up to time $T$.

My question is about how to interpretation behind implementing the expected value conditioned on $\mathcal{F}(t)$. Would this mean I just randomly generate a Wiener process $W(t)$ up to a time $t$, then fix this Wiener process, and then simulate the latter half up to time $T$ differently many times and calculate the average of $\frac{f(X(T), Y(T), K)}{M(T)}$? If so, wouldn't this depend a lot on the choice of the Wiener process up to time $t$? So, how does one calculate an expected value (like above), where $\mathcal{F}(t)$ is given?

Comment: If you are conditioning $\mathcal{F}_t$, then the values of $X_t$, $Y_t$ and $W_t$ are known (assuming $\mathcal{F}_t$ is generated from $W_t$). So you can just simulate the process starting at $t$.

Also, note replacing $\mu_i$ with $r$ to get the expectation under $\mathbb{Q}$ is only valid if $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are tradable.

Comment: But that is my last question in the post: doesn't the expected value depend on which  $X_t$, $Y_t$ and $W_t$ were chosen? How does one account for that? It doesn't feel like the expected value will just be a fixed quantity in this way

Comment: Conditioning on $\mathcal{F}_t$, means that $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are *known*, so there is no reason to choose them in a specific way (i.e. if $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are stock-prices, we could look up the price at time $t$). But of course the expected value depend on which values of $X_t$, $Y_t$ and $W_t$ are implied by the filtration.




From a practical point of view, just simulate $Z_s=W_s-W_t$ for $t\leq s \leq T$ (this is a BM with $Z_t = 0$, and independent of $W_t$), and use that to find $X_T-X_t$ and $Y_T-Y_t$.